# Anyone with iPhone apps that are loading external pages into apps?

Tags: iphone, cordova

I'm wondering if anyone has apps that have been accepted by Apple that rely on loading external mobile web pages as the app. Building Phonegap based apps would be a lot easier if I could load sections of the app directly from my server, I'm not sure if Apple allows this though.

Comment: Since I asked this & followed up last, I've had apps successfully added and actually ranked highly with this setup. I'm going as far as not only loading scripts now but actual rendered HTML partials into my app for rapid development. I've also read several white papers and reports that some major apps including Facebook actually uses to the same technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems with an app which loads content from your servers. If I'm not mistaken the iPad App Store does the same.

Answer (score 1):

Loading external JavaScript is definitely a no-no.  Loading content should be OK, so as long as those pages don't have any JavaScript (or too much JavaScript), you should be good.  That's kind of the problem with IOS development, you never know what Apple is going to decide breaks their TOS.  Basically I think they want to be reviewing the Application as a whole, and not having you able to slip new functionality in without their approving it (so you can't get an app approved and then change it so that it violates the TOS after it is approved).

Comment: I'd like to note that since asking this question a few apps of mine have been accepted and are on the app store that are loading a fair amount of remote javascript files for functionality and ads (admob). Since it's common practice to do this for mobile web ads, I'm assuming apple doesn't mind.

Comment: @franklinstine, thanks for the update. Very helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect it to be rejected? There are *browsers* in the app store, and all they do is load external content.

Comment: Yes but those browsers require the user to dictate the content they want to view. I can imagine a scenario that would have Apple concerned. For example Kris creates a Poker game that loads the pictures of the cards from the web. Apple approves and then once in the store he changes the pictures of the cards to XXX related playing cards that violate Apple's TOS. Something like that, if all the references are local Apple knows that it can't change without a new submission. With external content the app can change without going through the approval process.

Answer (score 0):

The cross-domain security policy applies to external web pages.

The cross-domain security policy does not affect PhoneGap applications. Since the html files are called by webkit with the file:// protocol, the security policy does not apply.

(in Android,you may grant android.permission.INTERNET to your app by edit the AndroidManifest.xml)

You should try fetching data from server not whole page with Js.